# How to automate the Apple Developer devices section

Tags: xcode, ios-provisioning, fastlane

I found that there are some really good scripts, like [fastlane.tools](http://fastlane.tools) for automating tedious tasks on the Apple Developer site, but I wasn't able to find something similar for the devices section. I have access to a couple of accounts so I will like to save some time.

I am interested in automatically adding, renaming and listing the devices in the portal. Any way I can do that more easily?

Answer (score 0):

You can do parts of it using [spaceship](https://github.com/fastlane/spaceship), at least registering and listing devices:

[Docs](https://github.com/fastlane/spaceship/blob/master/docs/DeveloperPortal.md#devices)

```
all_devices = Spaceship.device.all

# Register a new device
Spaceship.device.create!(name: "Private iPhone 6", udid: "5814abb3...")
```